# Condition to check whether the webservice response data is already inserted in sqlite in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i have *already inserted* my first data. *My issue* is when i go to insert the next data the loop count from the first data and ends with last data

```
-(void)GetAllSplitDataHandler:(id)value { 
 int j; 
 // NSError error; 
 if([value isKindOfClass:[NSError class]])
 { 
     NSLog(@"%@", value); return; 
  } 
 // Handle faults 
 if([value isKindOfClass:[SoapFault class]]) 
 { 
  NSLog(@"%@", value); 
  return; 
 } 
 NSMutableArray result = (NSMutableArray*)value; 
 NSLog(@"GetAllAtheleteHandler returned the value: %@", result ); 
 if([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",result] isEqualToString:@"1"]){ 

 NSLog(@"Result Count :: %d",[result count]); 
     for (int i =0; i<[result count]; i++) {

NSMutableDictionary *dic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];


    [dic setValue:[[result objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"entity1"] forKey:@"entity1"];
    [dic setValue:[[result objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"entity2"] forKey:@"entity2"];

    DAL *objDAL=[[DAL alloc]initDatabase:@"Abc.sqlite"];
    j = [objDAL insertRecord1:dic inTable:@"Abc"];


    if (j == 0) {
        NSLog(@"Inserted Successfully");

    }
    else if(j == -1)
    {
        NSLog(@"Insertion Failed");
       // NSAssert1(0, @"Insertion Failure '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: please put some amount of code which u tried yet.

Comment: @Roma please don't post code in comment, edit your question instead

Answer (score 0):

You can save the id (in `NSUserDefaults`) data which you have inserted last and when you call the webservice for next time you just insert data from the id next to the previously saved id.

Comment: @Roma code for storing data?and what response you are getting from webservice which is unique

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of you data value as a unique key constraint in your database . If that key will be duplicated then it will not insert the row in the database.

Comment: You dont have to code anything from your project .tell me your name of all column in database table